# How do I find a solution of a set of ODEs?

Tags: differential-equations

I have a set of ODEs from a paper on epidemic simulations. I tried to solve them using `DSolve` like this:

```
DSolve[
  {S'[t] == -r S[t]Y[t],
   Y'[t] == r S[t]Y[t] - a Y[t],
   R'[t] == a Y[t]},
  {S[t], Y[t], R[t}, t]
```

and it worked. Then I set boundary conditions `S[0] == 999, Y[0] == 1, R[0] == 0` and it said this:

> For some branches of the general solution, unable to solve the conditions.

I know that it should be pretty self-explanatory, but I think that I'm doing something wrong. I trust the equations because I trust the paper they came from, and I trust the boundary conditions because I think that they are reasonable for the context of epidemic simulation. I tried the boundary condition `S[0] == 0.99, Y[0] == 0.01, R[0] == 0` and it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have some special reasons for using `DSolve`? Usually [`NDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) is used for this kind of problems.

Comment: `With[{a = 1, r = 1}, 
  NDSolve[{S'[t] == -r S[t] Y[t], Y'[t] == r S[t] Y[t] - a Y[t], 
    R'[t] == a Y[t], S[0] == 999, Y[0] == 1, R[0] == 1}, {S[t], Y[t], 
    R[t]}, {t, -5, 5}]];
Plot[{S[t], Y[t], R[t]} /. First[%], {t, 0, 5}]`

Comment: Like many (most?) systems of nonlinear differential equations, a closed-form analytical solution (like `DSolve` gives) doesn't exist.  [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2004.07833.pdf) gives an analytical approximation -- look how horrible it is!  That's why `NDSolve` is your best bet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem has no solution.

Comment: The system does have a symbolic solution, but while short, it's a bit of a bear.  Start with `DSolve[{S'[t] == -r S[t] Y[t], Y'[t] == r S[t] Y[t] - a Y[t]}, {S[t], Y[t]}, t]` and integrate to get `R[t]`. Starting with `{D[Log[S[t]], t] == -r Y[t], D[Log[Y[t]], t] == r S[t] - a}`, one can derive the implicit solution `-r Y[t] == r S[t] - a Log[S[t]] + C[1]`, where `t` may be replaced by `t + C[2]` due to autonomy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solutions with your boundary conditions with `NDSolveValue`, but I had to be careful in chossing values for `a` and `r`. Your equation are sensitive to the values of those parameters. Since I have no idea of what they mean in terms of your model, I found some values that produce reasonable looking plots by trial-and-error.

Here is the code:

```
{sF, yF, rF} =
  With[{a = 5/2, r = 1/50},
    NDSolveValue[
      {S'[t] == -r S[t] Y[t], 
       Y'[t] == r S[t] Y[t] - a Y[t], 
       R'[t] == a Y[t],
       S[0] == 999, Y[0] == 1, R[0] == 1},
      {S, Y, R}, {t, 0, 2}]];

GraphicsColumn[
  MapThread[
    Plot[#1[t], {t, 0, 2},PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"t", #2}] &,
    {{sF, yF, rF}, {"S", "Y", "R"}}]]
```

[image: plots]

**Note**

This system of ODEs looks to me like some kind of variant on the Lotka–Volterra equations for predator-prey populations. Such models are known to be very sensitive to the values of their parameters. Some choices produce chaos and others produce strange attractors.